# Reading an URL with fopen + fgetcsv: does it use a cache?

Tags: php, caching, fopen, fgetcsv

I have a CSV online which is sometimes updated. I'm opening and reading it with:

```
$f = fopen("http://www.example.com/myfile.csv", "r"); 
$headers = fgetcsv($f); 
while ($row = fgetcsv($f)) 
{
    echo $row[0];
}
fclose($f);
```

Sometimes I notice the following problem: I know that the online CSV is already updated, but it seems that this PHP code reads an older version of the CSV (that was read previously a few seconds/minutes before by a precedent call of the same PHP code), **like if it would use a cached version of myfile.csv.**

**Where is the cache setting for `fopen($url, "r")`?** Is there a way to force re-download the URL and bypass any cache system?

PS: Internally, what does `fopen` use for opening non-filesystem-files but distant files/internet URLs?

Comment: You can use the function `clearstatcache();`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: I wouldn't expect PHP to use a cache automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact `fopen` does not seem to be affected by caching, the documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php states:

> Affected functions include stat(), lstat(), file_exists(), is_writable(), is_readable(), is_executable(), is_file(), is_dir(), is_link(), filectime(), fileatime(), filemtime(), fileinode(), filegroup(), fileowner(), filesize(), filetype(), and fileperms()